# Как добавить ActionBar на PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Не понимаю почему страница с настройками не содержит `ActionBar`. Манифест:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TEST"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Settings"/>
</application>
```

т.е. `<activity android:name=".Settings"/>` стоит в теге `application`, в котором стоит стиль (тема) `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. При этом на главном экране `ActionBar` присутствует, а на `PreferenceActivity` - нет.

`styles.xml` стандартный

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

При использовании темы `AppCompat` `ActionBar` можно увидеть только в активити унаследованных от `ActionBarActivity`(устаревший) или `AppCompatActivity`.
Для `PreferenceActivity`аналога для темы `AppCompat` еще не написали, поэтому есть два варианта:

1. Простой. В активити унаследованной от `AppCompatActivity` разместить `PreferenceFragment`.
2. Сложный. В `PreferenceActivity` интегрировать `AppCompatDelegate`.
3. Альтернативный. Вместо `ActionBar` использовать `Toolbar`.

[Подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849193/how-to-add-action-bar-from-support-library-into-preferenceactivity)